# language model kneser-ney: ARPA file values

Tags: math

I am currently writing a program in Python to compute language models from a text file.

I am using the following formula for Kneser-Ney smoothing:
[Kneser-Ney smoothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgO4O.png)
[Speech and Language Processing. Daniel Jurafsky & James H. Martin.]

I would like to have an output file in ARPA.

My question is which values from the formula go into the ARPA output. What is the **probability** what is the **backoff** weight?